# POST request using fetch with async/await on submit

Tags: reactjs, api, post, async-await

I want to POST to a login form using React JSX and JWT API auth already installed. I don't want to use axios post, instead I want to use the hooks method useState, useEffect with async/await and onFormSubmit function. How do I POST the data values username and password between the state and effect. thanks

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
    userNiceName: '',
    userEmail: '',
    loggedIn: false,
    loading: false,
    error: ''
})


useEffect(() => {

}, [])

const postData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/react/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', requestOptions )
    const login = await response.json()
    const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }


const onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = {
        username: e.target[0].value,
        password: e.target[2].value,
    }
```

Comment: `useEffect` is for use of code that should run every time your component updates, a replacement for `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. It looks like you should just be using an onSubmit event callback (which is still how events are handled even with react hooks). This page may help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html .

Answer (score 0):

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
})
    

const [logindata, setLogindata] = useState({
    userNiceName: '',
    userEmail: '',
    loggedIn: false,
    loading: false,
    error: ''
})


useEffect(() => {
    postData()
    return ()=>{}
    }, [login])
    
    const postData = async () => {
    
    const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(login)
            }
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8888/react/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', requestOptions )
        const loginresp = await response.json()
    setLogindata({...logindata, ...loginresp})
    }
       
    
    
    const onFormSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const data = {
            username: e.target[0].value,
            password: e.target[2].value,
        }
        setLogin({...login,...data})
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I have an error Cannot access 'requestOptions' before initialization
I've tried to change the order for the requestOptions and bring it above the fetch URL, but the JSON stringify login data then will be initiliazed before the response.

Comment: I made a change. Try again

Comment: Hi Rafael, 

On my comments, I mentioned an error also for [login] state Cannot access 'login' before initialization. As you can see the JSON stringify the login data before the response is initiated?

The code need a bit fo tweaking still.

Comment: @HassanHafez check the changes I made

Comment: I've tried again and because of body: JSON.stringify(login) it causes 

[POST http://localhost:8888/react/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token 403 (Forbidden)]

Comment: Maybe That's a CORS problem